# Error in Nhibernate automapping as object refrence not set to an instance

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapper

I am pretty new to automapping through have used nhibernate mapping earlier. This is my session factory

```
 return Fluently.Configure()
                     .Database(
                         MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                             ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Royal"].ConnectionString))
                     .Mappings(m =>
                               m.AutoMappings
                                   .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<EmployeeLogin>().UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf
                                            <EmployeeLoginMap>()
                                            .Conventions.Setup(x => x.Add<PrimarykeyConvention>( new PrimarykeyConvention()))
                                   ))
                     .BuildSessionFactory();
```

This is my EmployeeLoginMap Class for mapping the Employee_Login Table

```
public class EmployeeLoginMap : IAutoMappingOverride<EmployeeLogin>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<EmployeeLogin> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("employee_login");
        mapping.Id(x => x.EmpId, "EmpId");
    }
}
```

This is the Primary Key Convention for the automapping:

```
public class PrimarykeyConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance target)
    {
        target.Column(target.EntityType.Name + "Id");
        target.GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }
}
```

And this my EmployeeLogin Domain

```
 public class EmployeeLogin
{
    public String EmpId { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String Dob { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String BranchCode { get; set; }
    public String EntryPerm { get; set; }
    public String LastModified { get; set; }
    public String ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to access this using `isession = GetSession();`

It calls the sessionfactory method for instance . and there it gets an error in fluent mapping for generating sessionfactory iteself as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: a complete Stacktrace would help a lot, but my guess would be that connectionstring "Royal" is missing in the appconfig

Comment: yes that was the problem i guessed . it turned out to be true ... thanks +1 for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that connectionstring "Royal" is missing in the appconfig.